# Prove the following elementary properties of the group character

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm reading the book appendix on group theory of the book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen & Chuang. I'm having trouble with exercises A2.11 and A2.12. This isn't homework proper, since I'm self-studying this book.

We adopt the following definitions. Let $G$ be a **finite** group which is represented by a matrix group $H\subset M_n$, where $M_n$ is the 
set of all $n\times n$ complex matrices. The character function defined on $G$ is given by $\chi(g) = \text{tr}\,M$, where $g\in G$ and $M\in M_n$ is the matrix that represents $g$. I'm not interested in the more abstract generalizations of this definition.

I need some help proving the following statements:

1. $|\chi(g)|\leq n$
2. $|\chi(g)| = n$ implies $M=e^{\theta I}$, where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
3. $\chi(g^{-1}) = \chi^*(g)$
4. Every matrix group is equivalent to a unitary matrix group.

It's the first time I meet representation theory, and I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Hint: $\chi(g)$ is conjugate to an upper triangular matrix. Since it has finite order, what can the diagonal elements possibly be?

Comment: So the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries all $n$ has trace $n^2>n$, and certainly lies in a matrix group, so 1) doesn't seem right. This leads me to believe you might be omitting hypotheses by accident. Could this be possible? Or maybe I'm overlooking something... Maybe the group is finite?

Comment: Ahh, I implicitly assumed the group to be finite, as that is necessary for the statements to be true.

Comment: becko, this is really too many questions for a single question. It's usually nicer if you separate them. Cluster questions only if they are really hard to separate. These seem to be four disparate facts that don't really rely on each other.

Comment: @rschwieb I clustered them together because they are part of the same exercise of Nielsen's book. Also, I thought that the same basic set of ideas would serve to prove all the properties.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, the group is finite. I'm fixing the question.

Comment: @becko I understand, and I'm not saying you did anything wrong. Authors have the luxury of asking questions in lists, but that can lead to complications for answerers (should they answer if they can do all but one?) I'm just saying it's something to take into consideration in the future. Maybe you're right: maybe one comment will prove them all :)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Think you can hint them all in one fell swoop in a solution?

Comment: @rschwieb For example, if the character function is invariant under different representations, then the 4'th property implies all the others. Also, 1. and 2. seem closely related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\value}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$Everything stems from the fact that if the order of $G$ is $k$, then $g^{k} = 1$, and thus $M^{k} = I$, the identity matrix, that is, $M$ is a root of $x^{k} - 1$. This is a polynomial with distinct roots, so $M$ can be diagonalized, with $k$-th roots of unity on the diagonal. Proceed from here.

For instance, if the roots of unity on the diagonal of $M$ are $\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{n}$, then
$$
\value{\chi(g)} = \value{\alpha_{1} + \dots + \alpha_{n}} \le \value{\alpha_{1}} + \dots + \value{\alpha_{n}} = n.
$$

Comment: I knew there was a simple idea I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @becko, you're welcome!